# GFCI will not allow things to work

Tags: electrical

We purchased a newly remodeled home last summer & over the holidays I received a treadmill. The treadmill will not work in any 
of the outlets bc they are all GFCI protected. Can someone please help me solve this ANNOYING problem!

Comment: This sounds like there is another issue. It sounds like the GFCI is doing it's job and protecting you from being electrocuted (i.e. something wrong with your treadmill). Do other things work in those outlets?

Comment: Yes, other things work in the outlet(s). The treadmill company said it wouldn't work on GFCI outlets. When we first moved in we had to fix another outlet bc the microwave and hood vent light wouldn't work at the same time. GFCI in my opinion is TOO SENSITIVE. Can I remove the GFCI from an outlet?

Comment: @Pravat -- the treadmill's the problem, not the GFCI, most likely -- what make/model/vintage is it?  Also, does it have any fancy pushbutton controls on it?

Answer (score 3):

Big AC motors (refrigerators, air conditioners, washing machines, and exercise equipment) can create large current spikes when they start up - especially if they need to fill a capacitor as part of their operation.

A GFCI will detect current going out but not returning. Sounds like the GFCIs are working correctly. This is by design to catch a situation where the user of an appliance become part of the ground path, and why GFCIs can save lives. They work by measuring the current leaving the GFCI device on the hot wire and returning on the neutral wire. If currents do not match within some close tolerance level, the assumption is the current is leaking somewhere; possibly cooking the flesh of a human or pet as it seeks ground. A device such as your treadmill may have a current mismatch that is completely legitimate, but incompatible with a GFCI-protected branch circuit.

You will need to plug your treadmill into an outlet that is not GFCI-protected. If one is not available, I recommend contacting a licensed electrician to assess the situation and possibly install a new circuit for the treadmill in accordance with whatever electrical code is relevant in your location.

Comment: @Pravat, it sounds like this answer is acceptable. You should click the checkmark to indicate this. Great answer, btw!

Answer (score 1):

Do they have such a thing as an **isolation transformer** where you are?  This is not a step-up/down transformer (which use the same primary).  This would look similar, but would have primary and secondary separate, isolated from each other, with the same voltage on both sides.

This converts the load into a transformer load, which should be unlikely to trip the GFCI.  If the machine is actually ground-faulting, it will faulting to the isolated secondary, which will increase safety somewhat.  Still not a good thing.